# subversion starting as forked process

Tags: svn, ubuntu

How do I setup subversion as forked process using ubuntu server 9.10 and subversion 1.6?

I've tried svnserve -i but the svnbook says this is wrong.

I followed the svnbook which told me to tell me

/etc/services

```
svn           3690/tcp   # Subversion
svn           3690/udp   # Subversion
```

/etc/inetd.conf

```
svn stream tcp nowait svnowner /usr/bin/svnserve svnserve -i
```

but no svnserve process gets started ???????
 th
Any help would be greatly appriciated. Very confused!!!

I was told forked processes are safer since they will finish off before subversion quits

Comment: Or "Why don't I see deamon processes when I've setup inetd to run the process on demand?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see a svnserve process using inetd until a connection is made to SVN at port 3690.